# how to filter dataset with ArrayType column such that Array doesn't contain duplicates

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, arraylist

I have dataset as

```
+-------+------+
|    A  |    B |
+-------+------+
|      a| [1,2]  |
|      a| [2,2]  |
|      a| [1,3]  |
|      a| [1,2,3]|
|      a| [1,1,3]|
```

B column is ArrayType and some list have duplicates within itself . I need to filter only row that has non-duplicates elements in the list.

Expected REsult:

```
+-------+------+
|    A  |    B |
+-------+------+
|      a| [1,2]  |
|      a| [1,3]  |
|      a| [1,2,3]|
```

second row is dropped as it has duplicate 2, 5th is dropped as it has duplicate 1.

How can I get this in pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = [("Alice", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
        ("Bob", [6, 7, 8, 8, 9]),
        ("Charlie", [10, 11, 12, 13, 14])]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Numbers"])

df_d = df.withColumn("HasD", size(col("Numbers")) > size(array_distinct(col("Numbers")))). \
    where(col("HasD") == False)

df_d.show()
```